# Error: Input number format exception

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I am trying to use the source code from the cluster-algorithms-java-alpha library this is the link

https://code.google.com/p/cluster-algorithms-java-alpha/source/browse/tags/rewritepending/src/tests/validationIndices/SilhouetteIndexTest.java?r=6

When I try to run it it runs perfectly.

I have taken the IRIS dataset from the uci repository

I have modified the code

```
//this.trivialTestset =InputReader.readFromfile("C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\Coding\\Clusterer\\src\\easy.valid");

    this.trivialTestset =InputReader.readFromfile("C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\Coding\\Clusterer\\src\\iris.txt");
```

I m getting these errors

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at input.FeatureVector.<init>(FeatureVector.java:17)
at input.InputReader.readFromfile(InputReader.java:34)
at input.InputReader.readFromfile(InputReader.java:61)
at tests.validationIndices.SilhouetteIndexTest.setup(SilhouetteIndexTest.java:27)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dataset is not formatted properly.

The `easy.valid` file is properly formatted, make sure the `iris.txt` file is formatted the exact same.

If it's not, you're gonna have to write your own input parser.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the stacktrace, your program tried to execute `Integer.parseInt()` for the string `"5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa"`. But this string isn't integer number.
Firstly, there are only double values in this string. Secondly, you can see text ending.